# Someone know how is the process and processing times for the European passport return service?

Tags: visa, resident-permit, uk-visa

I want to apply for the Registration certificate with my partner. We are married and one is EU and the other is non EU. The Family permit will be expired in 1 month, but we need to travel back and forth. We want to ask the registration certificate for the EU and add in the application the non EU spouse in order to get the residence card for the non EU. At the moment of the application, We are going to use the European passport return service, but We don't know if the NON EU passport of the spouse is being returned or not.

Do you know if they return both passports?

Do we have to go with all the documents and submit them along with the certificated copy that they give us? or Do they give as the copy and then we have to submit the documents?

Do you know If there is any problem if We fist ask the residence card and then the EEA FM in an EU country (not UK)? This assuming that they returned the passports. Because I searched in internet that is the only way to travel meanwhile the residence card is being processing for the non EU.

When Do We have to make the appointment for the passport return service? Before to apply online to the registration certificated or after?

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Someone know how is the process and processing times for the European passport return service?

I assume that you are asking because it you're concerned about how long you will have to be without your passport.  I am not sure of the processing times, but if I understand the [service description](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/european-passport-return-service) correctly, you never leave your passports with them.

Instead, you "take your passports to a participating local authority for verification and copying," after which the local authority "send[s] the copy to the Home Office."

This implies that you are in possession of your passports when you leave the local authority office.

> Do you know if they return both passports?

Surely they must.  Otherwise, what would be the point of "includ[ing] any family members (of any nationality) who you have included in your online application"?

> Do we have to go with all the documents and submit them along with the certificated copy that they give us?  Or do they give as the copy and then we have to submit the documents?

It sounds like they don't give you the certified copy, but rather send it directly to the Home Office (see above).  As to what you need to bring, the site has the answer:

> You will need to bring:
>
> - your original passports
> - a copy of your checklist and supporting documents
> - a printed copy of your application form

Note this warning:

> You must contact a local authority to book an appointment to use this service. You’ll need to attend an appointment with them within 5 working days of submitting your online application, so you may want to book one before you submit this application.

I would therefore recommend that you do the following:

1. Book an appointment for the passport return service
2. Five days before the appointment, submit your online application
3. Assemble your checklist, supporting documents, and printed application form
4. Bring this all with your passports to the appointment.  The local authority agent who assists you ought to know what needs to be done with each part of the paperwork